# SQL Server 2022: AlwaysOn AG databases can not sync after applying CU6 or higher

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2022

The setup is:
OS - Win Server 2022 & MSSQL - SQL Server 2022.
AlwaysOn Availability Groups are enabled on two (primary + secondary) replicas and use WSFC.
Several availability groups are created and a database in each of them.
AGs are configured with Sync Commit and Automatic failover mode, also they use dedicated separate VLAN for data sync.

**The issue we noticed is that after applying CU6 or higher ones , in case of we restart any of two replica hosts,
on the secondary replica not all databases switch back to Synchronized state, part of them remain in Not Synchronizing state .**

Any ideas what could be the reason of that behavior change? Had someone similar issue ?

Comment: Seems like a weak correlation, is there any data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as an additional info , 
the following event appears in the sql server error logs after the replica restarts:

Could not process the operation. Always On Availability Groups replica manager is waiting for the host computer to start a Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) cluster and join it. Either the local computer is not a cluster node, or the local cluster node is not online. If the computer is a cluster node, wait for it to join the cluster. If the computer is not a cluster node, add the computer to a WSFC cluster. Then, retry the operation.